# Update loss value each batch to get an averaged epoch loss

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create an operation similar to the one you can obtain using tf.metrics and their update_op value. When you execute this in tf:

```
acc, update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(tf.argmax(probs, 1), labels, name="accuracy")
```

The *update_op* value is updated in each call.

So I want to do the same with the loss. I have tried the following code:
update_loss = tf.Variable(0., name="loss")

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=model.logits, labels=labels))
update_loss.assign(update_loss + loss)
```

But always I run:

```
init_vars = [tf.local_variables_initializer(), 

tf.global_variables_initializer()]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    loss_val = sess.run(update_loss)
```

I get a value of 0. Any idea?

### EDIT:

I must point that the value of tensor **loss** is not zero during the execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have discovered a plausible solution which can work but it's not really solving my doubt... based on [this post](https://steemit.com/machine-learning/@ronny.rest/avoiding-headaches-with-tf-metrics) (5.2 Tensorflow - Batch accuracy
)

It consists on creating a function that uses the last obtained loss value and pass it to a function through feed_dict that updates a placeholder with the cumulative value:

```
session.run(tf_metric_update, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```